How to run a query for every distinct value in a column
I am new to sql and am trying to complete my first project
I have this query
SELECT Nationality, SUM(`Kill`) AS total_kills_by_region
FROM vct2
WHERE Nationality = 'United States';

It selects the sum of total kills in a valorant championship where the player's nationality is the united states. All of the nationality types are Nationality 'Argentina', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Finland', 'France', 'International', 'Kazakhstan', 'Latvia', 'South Korea', 'Sweeden', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'United Kingdom', 'United States'.
Do I have to just copy and paste this query over and over again to get the results for all of these?
I plan to compile a map in tableau with the results.
I am not sure exactly how to go about this.

I have formatted the request for you. For code use the {} button (or simply put four additional blanks in front of each code line yourself).

You are looking for GROUP BY:
SELECT nationality, SUM(kill) AS total_kills_by_region 
FROM vct2 
GROUP BY nationality
ORDER BY nationality;

